# Having dynamic subreports in a repeating list object in SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm rendering reports in ASP.NET and I wanted to let the users have ad hoc reports then generate it into PDF. Instead of manually adding subreports in the parent report file and toggling visibility when needed, I plan to have a list object repeat a nested sub-report object then bind which report file to use, dataset and parameters needed to run the report.

I'm currently scourging Google for a solid tutorial on this and still I have no proper lead. So now I'm desperate to know whether this is possible. Anyone here tried this before?

Answer (score 3):

It is surely possible. Open a table and get a Subreport in that table. Group the table by the argument you want to pass in as report argument. Then you can rightclick on your subreport item (make sure you're really on the subreport and not the tablecell) and define the arguments you want to get into. Left side without @-sign and right side with:

- rightclick on subreport
- subreport properties
- parameters
- First the argument for your subreport (i.e.: MyArgument1)
- then the argument from your current report (i.e.: @Parameter1 or your Group)

Should do the trick ;-). If you have questions just ask.